# How to read a dataset into pandas and leave out rows with uneven column count

Tags: python, pandas, ragged

I am trying to read a dataset, which has few rows with uneven column count ('ragged'). I want to leave out those rows and read the rest of the rows. Is it possible in pandas instead of breaking the dataset into separate data frames and combining them?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with sample data that reproduces the problem? If you can read it in, then you'd just have to remove the bad lines after the fact. Otherwise, you might need the `error_bad_lines` argument.

Comment: Yes, please show a simple MCVE. Also do you need to handle the case where those rows do have the full column count, but happen to contain (explicit) NAs? If yes, post an MCVE which stresses that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have uneven columns, but want to drop any rows that don't have every column.  If so, simply read the entire data set (read_csv) and then call dropna() on the dataframe.   dropna() has a swarg called 'how' which defaults to 'any' ... that is, if any of the items in the given row (or column) are NA.  (Consider also doing 'inplace=True').  See also: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: But this hack will also drop those rows which **did** have the full column count, but which happened to contain NAs. ('explicit NAs' rather than 'NAs due to omitting the column')